# Shimei's children( Shelomoth and Haziel and Haran ) as being part of the household of Ladan, Shimei's brother

Tags: hebrew-bible, manuscript

1 Chronicles 23:7-11 New American Standard Bible (NASB)

> <sup>**7**</sup> **Of the Gershonites were Ladan and Shimei. <sup>**8**</sup> The sons of Ladan were Jehiel the first and Zetham and Joel, three. <sup>**9**</sup> The sons of Shimei were Shelomoth and Haziel and Haran, three. These were the heads of the fathers’ households of Ladan.** <sup>**10**</sup> The sons of Shimei were Jahath, Zina, Jeush and Beriah. These four were the sons of Shimei. <sup>**11**</sup> Jahath was the first and Zizah the second; but Jeush and Beriah did not have many sons, so they became a father’s household, one class.

Does the biblical scripture impute Shimei's children(Shelomoth and Haziel and Haran ) as being part of the household of Ladan, Shimei's brother?

Or Did the Old Testament scribes make a mistake as they were writing the sentences in order? To elaborate, was the scripture that states "These were the heads of the fathers’ households of Ladan" have been part of 1 Chronicles 23:8?

Comment: There is more than one Shimei(1Chr 6:42-43).

Comment: @user21676 please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

This was a challenging question!  Being a student of Hebrew, I have scrutinized the text in Hebrew in an attempt to solve the riddle.  I believe I may have managed to do so.

There are several important points to consider when looking at this passage.

**Point 1**

The most important point is that the original text did not have verse numbers, nor punctuation.  The additional versification and punctuation in English cannot be relied upon as correctly portraying the message of the original Hebrew.

**Point 2**

Secondly, the article ("the") in Hebrew is used for grammatical purposes that also do not perfectly align to English.  It may not always be true that making a word definite in Hebrew means it is the *only* defined thing to the exclusion of other possibilities.  I'll try to explain why this may be important shortly.

**Point 3**

Thirdly, there is no "of" in Hebrew: this word comes into the English translation from what are called *construct chains* in Hebrew where two (or more) nouns are strung together, the first of which will appear in *construct state* (i.e. it is spelled differently from its absolute/normal form).  In some cases, two consecutive nouns might appear to be in construct that should be separate, grammatically, and these are separated by the use of the preposition "le" (Hebrew *lamed*), because the insertion of any word other than an article between two nouns will mean that they cannot be in a construct relationship with each other.

### Rearrangement of the Text

Starting with the first point, let us consider how the verses might be better arranged, following which I will explain the justification for these adjustments.

| Reference | KJV Text | *Rearranged* |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1Chr 23:6 | And David divided them into courses among the sons of Levi, namely, Gershon, Kohath, and Merari. | And David divided them into courses among the sons of Levi, namely, Gershon, Kohath, and Merari. |
| 1Chr 23:7 | Of the Gershonites were, Laadan, and Shimei. | Of the Gershonites were, Laadan, and Shimei. |
| 1Chr 23:8 | The sons of Laadan; the chief was Jehiel, and Zetham, and Joel, three. | The sons of Laadan; the chief was Jehiel, and Zetham, and Joel, three. |
| 1Chr 23:9 | The sons of Shimei; Shelomith, and Haziel, and Haran, three. These were the chief of the fathers of Laadan. | The sons of Shimei; Shelomith, and Haziel, and Haran, three. These were the chief of the fathers: of Laadan, **and the sons of Shimei.** |
| 1Chr 23:10 | And the sons of Shimei were, Jahath, Zina, and Jeush, and Beriah. These four were the sons of Shimei. | Jahath, Zina, and Jeush, and Beriah: these four were the sons of Shimei. |
| 1Chr 23:11 | And Jahath was the chief, and Zizah the second: but Jeush and Beriah had not many sons; therefore they were in one reckoning, according to their father's house. | And Jahath was the chief, and Zizah the second: but Jeush and Beriah had not many sons; therefore they were in one reckoning, according to their father's house. |

Notice that I have changed only verses 9 and 10, moving one phrase from verse 10 back up to verse 9, then repunctuating.  This change still leaves a divide between two lists of Shimei's sons, but does not change the original ordering of words from the Hebrew.  That divide is where we next focus.

### Additional Grammatical Details

Words are definite in Hebrew for three reasons:

1. It is a proper name;
2. It has a pronominal suffix; or
3. It has the article ("the") prefix.

In other words, even without the article in Hebrew, the translation may require the use of "the."  Such is the case with all of the construct chains ending in a name, because the proper name makes the whole chain *definite*.

So when we see "sons *of* Shimei," because "Shimei" is definite, the whole chain is definite, and the translation must be "**the** sons *of* Shimei."

Remembering point three above, a construct chain can be broken by the use of a *lamed* prefix to a following noun.  Had there been a *lamed* before "Shimei," the translation might have read "sons of Shimei," without the definite article. No prepositional *lamed* is present in the text of either verse 9 or 10, so "the sons of Shimei" is a proper translation.

**Is one list or the other to be understood as presenting *all* of Shimei's sons?**

The question now arises: Does the *definite* status of "the sons of Shimei" mean that these could be his *only* sons?

My conclusion to this question is, "No."  Consider the following two verses from chapter 4 of Numbers in support of this.

> And to the office of **Eleazar the son of Aaron** the priest
> pertaineth the oil for the light, and the sweet incense, and the daily
> meat offering, and the anointing oil, and the oversight of all the
> tabernacle, and of all that therein is, in the sanctuary, and in the
> vessels thereof. (Numbers 4:16, KJV)
>
> This is the service of the families of the sons of Gershon in the
> tabernacle of the congregation: and their charge shall be under the
> hand of **Ithamar the son of Aaron** the priest. (Numbers 4:28, KJV)

Again, because "Aaron" is a proper name, "son (construct state) Aaron" in Hebrew must be translated as "**the** son *of* Aaron."  Yet, clearly, Aaron had more than one son.

The same principle applies here to Shimei.  Verse 9 is defining the *heads* of the family, and verse 10 names the sons who were not the heads of the family.

### Conclusion

The translation to English was made awkward by the improper verse divisions which had been added to the Hebrew.  The original Hebrew does not indicate that Shimei's sons are included among Laadan's sons.  The Old Testament scribes are not at fault here--it is an issue of problematic versification and translation.